# multiple render in rails controller action while calling an api

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I want that my rails controller index action to render multiple output at once , my controller:

```
 class Api::V1::Ola::OlaBookingsController < ApplicationController
 def index
   lat = params[:lat].to_s
   long = params[:long].to_s
   drop_lat = params[:drop_lat].to_s
   drop_lng = params[:drop_lng].to_s    
   ola_query = { 
     "pickup_lat" => lat,
     "pickup_lng" => long,
     "drop_lat" => drop_lat ,
     "drop_lng" => drop_lng
   }
   ola_body = {
     "pickup_lat" => lat,
     "pickup_lng" => long,
     "drop_lat" => drop_lat,
     "drop_lng" => drop_lng,
     "pickup_mode" => "NOW",
     "category" => "auto"
   } 
   ola_headers = {
     "Authorization" => "Bearer ", 
     "X-APP-TOKEN" => ""
   }

   @ola_products = HTTParty.get(
     "http://sandbox-t.olacabs.com/v1/products", 
     :query => ola_query,
     :headers => ola_headers
   ).parsed_response

   @ola_booking = HTTParty.post(
     "http://sandbox-t.olacabs.com/v1/bookings/create ", 
     :body => ola_body,
     :headers => ola_headers
   ).parsed_response

  render :json => @ola_booking 
  render :json => @ola_products 
  end
end
```

I want both responses to be coming on controller without generating a viw.
But it gives error "multiple render not possible" , how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You can not have 2 renders what you can do is combine the 2 objects one after the other like

```
render :json => @ola_booking.to_json + @ola_products.to_json
```

you should try it out and let me know how it worked

Comment: getting error undefined method `+' for #<Hash:0x007fe13cf39da8>

Comment: I think you want to merge the two hashes like this: `render json: @ola_booking.merge(@ola_products)`.

Comment: @AmarpreetJethra can you post what is the value of `@ola_booking` as well the value of `@ola_products `

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json  { render :json => {:ola_booking => @ola_booking, 
                                  :ola_products => @ola_products }}
end
```